# Visual Studio Code append to existing import

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Vscode has an auto import functionality which will append the new imported item to a list if it exists:

`import { fun1 } from "./utils"`

then if I trigger auto-import of fun2 from utils it will look like:

`import { fun1, fun2 } from "./utils"`

How does it add fun2 to that list?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a [CodeActionProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#CodeActionProvider) (which is what's used for the light bulb feature). The key here is to create [workspace edits](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#WorkspaceEdit) that allow manipulating the content of a document (addressed by the given URI).